# Access method in controller from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model

Just started using Rails, figuring out how to access a method in my model.

In the controller i try the follwoing:
`@testString = Work.testMethod`

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base<br>
  def testMethod
    return "string from test method"
  end
end
```

This results in 'NoMethodError in WorksController#index' (undefined method).
I would appreciate some assistance.

And.. why does rails appends an 's' to the controller name when scaffolding 'work'? Model name is Work and controller is: works_controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept which you are talking of is introducing a `class` method. The method needs to be defined on the `Work` class itself with the help of the `self` keyword.

It can be done as follows:

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.testMethod
     return "string from test method"
   end
end
```

To answer your second question, Rails being an opinionated framework, forces the pattern of pluralizing your Controller and Table names. This is really for being more grammatically correct.

In case you wish to tweak the pluralization you can do so by using the [Inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `self`:

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
   MY_MESSAGE = "ALL THE BEST"

   def self.testMethod
     return "string from test method"
   end
end
```

`self` is used to call class level method. Now you can call it anywhere like below:

```
Work.testMethod #=> "string from test method"
Work::MY_MESSAGE #=> "ALL THE BEST"
```

If you use `instance_level` method you need to create instance of `class` then you can call method on object. But model instance are created when you want to create new record so I prefer using `self` methods when you don't want to create record.

If you have record you can invoke:

```
 class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
   def testMethod
     return "string from test method"
   end
end

work_record = Work.find(your_condition)
work_record.testMethod
```

Comment: thx, this works, simple enough. How does this work with variables declared in Models? Accessing them from the controller i mean.

Comment: you mean `constant` variable??

Comment: based on examples above i am able to access the method in my Model, thx! Concerning the variable, i mean a var that is local to the Model. Accessible by methods in the Model to work with.